# how to perform the following query?

Tags: database, oracle10g

question is: List the client names that have placed the orders before the Month of ‘august’

I tried:

```
SELECT cname
FROM client_master c, sales_orders s 
WHERE c.clientno=s.clientno
AND s.orderdate < to_char(orderDate,'mm') ='AUG';
```

ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Can anybody please tell me what's wrong with the above query?

Comment: Look at `and s.orderdate < to_char(orderDate,'mm')='AUG'` again. What are you comparing with `=`, and what are you comparing with `<` ? You need to compare the table column value with a date, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider using a JOIN instead of listing the tables with commas. Then you need to adjust the last line to specify the order date should be before August 1st. You can do that this way:

```
SELECT cname
FROM client_master c
INNER JOIN sales_orders s 
ON c.clientno = s.clientno
WHERE s.orderdate < to_date('2016-08-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: You are still comparing a date with a string, so you are relying on implicit conversion and the session NLS settings. Did you mean to use an ANSI date literal, perhaps?

Comment: How do you know it's a string? I think we need to actually see what order date looks like from the OP. I will ask

Comment: You are comparing the column, which presumably is a date, with `'2016-08-01'` which is a string literal. If you wanted a date you need a date literal, `date '2016-08-01'`, or explicit conversion, `to_date('2016-08-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`. (What you have would *work* if your NLS_DATE_FORMAT was YYYY-MM-DD, but you can't safely assume that).

Comment: I gotcha. How does it look now?